# Elasticsearch group-by field

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by

I have some squid data like below:

```
{"requestresultcode": "TCP_MISS/200"},
{"requestresultcode": "TCP_MISS/200"},
{"requestresultcode": "TCP_MISS/302"},
{"requestresultcode": "TCP_MISS/504"},
{"requestresultcode": "TCP_MISS/200"},
{"requestresultcode": "ERR_CLIENT_ABORT/000"},
{"requestresultcode": "ERR_CLIENT_ABORT/200"},
{"requestresultcode": "ERR_CLIENT_ABORT/302"},
{"requestresultcode": "ERR_CLIENT_ABORT/502"},
{"requestresultcode": "ERR_CONNECT_FAIL/502"}
```

I want to group by the field, so I used aggregations terms to do it

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "agg1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cacheresultcode"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got the result:

```
"aggregations": {
    "agg1": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "200",
          "doc_count": 2011
        },
        {
          "key": "tcp_miss",
          "doc_count": 1740
        },
        {
          "key": "err_client_abort",
          "doc_count": 705
        },
        {
          "key": "302",
          "doc_count": 244
        },
        {
          "key": "000",
          "doc_count": 185
        },
        {
          "key": "502",
          "doc_count": 24
        },
        {
          "key": "err_connect_fail",
          "doc_count": 23
        },
        {
          "key": "504",
          "doc_count": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

It is a few different between use SQL, I think it should be like

- ERR_CLIENT_ABORT/000
- ERR_CLIENT_ABORT/200
- ERR_CLIENT_ABORT/302
- ERR_CLIENT_ABORT/502
- ERR_CONNECT_FAIL/502
- TCP_MISS/200
- TCP_MISS/302
- TCP_MISS/504

How should I do ?
Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Your `cacheresultcode` field is an analyzed string and you need to make it a `keyword` (i.e. a not analyzed string)

Comment: got it !! it's very useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the analyzed field somewhere else then you can use [multifields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) to have a keyword type for cacheresultcode.

**Mappings**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "document_type" : {
      "properties": {
        "cacheresultcode":{
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword" : {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query**

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "agg1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cacheresultcode.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, good, don't forget to use "keyword"